# How to play WMV in a WindowMediaPlayer activeX controlled by a flash component?

Tags: flash, video, wmp

How to play WMV in a WindowMediaPlayer activeX controlled by a flash component?

I've seen it done here: http://sport5.co.il/
Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see the two interacting would be to place both a WMP and a Flash component on a web page, then have JavaScript to manipulate the two. For example, you could have Flash buttons for play/stop/etc, and when those are clicked, javascript handles the click event and tells the WMP control to start/stop playing.

Does this help?